# How to set a checkbox value to checked after clicking on a link in Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, checkbox, link-to

I have an unordered list which I can expand by clicking on each list element.

**list.html.erb**

```
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox" unchecked>
<label for="toggle">
    <li>Implementing Bootstrap</li>
</label>
<div id="expand">
     ...
     ...
</div>
```

I am able to go from **main.html.erb** to **list.html.erb** right to the the list element by clicking on a link.

**main.html.erb**

```
<li><%= link_to "Implementing Bootstrap", list_path(:anchor => "toggle") %></li>
```

Additionally I want that the checkbox value is checked of the given linked element after I click on the link so the list element on **list.html.erb** will be exapneded right away.

**How can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

dont pretty but can work
you  can send params in link_to

```
<li><%= link_to "Implementing Bootstrap", list_path(:link_name => 'Implementing Bootstrap', :anchor => "toggle") %></li>
```

be sure in routes you have something like

```
get '/list/:link_name => 'lisk#METHODNAME',as: :list
```

in controller you can set this as class variable

```
@checkbox = params['link_name']
```

in view check @checkbox, something like this

```
<% if @checkbox == "Implementing Bootstrap" %> 
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox" checked>
<% else %>
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox" unchecked>
<% end %>
```